# Calculus - If the sum of an infinite series is the limit of the sequence of its partial sums, is it an infinitely small amount off?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Since the sequence of partial sums would never actually reach that value, would the sum of the infinite series be an infinitely small amount off of what it would be if it were possible to actually add together all of the terms?

For example the infinite series $\frac9{10^n}$ has a sum of $1$, but if you manually add the terms, they seem like they would be an infinitely small amount off of that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Take the following sequence: $x_n = 1/n$. Its limit is $0$.  However, when we say that the limit is $0$, we are not saying that $x_n$ will eventually have a term with value $0$. We are simply saying that it approaches $0$ as $n$ gets bigger and bigger.

The same happens with infinite sums. When we write: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n} = 1$$

We are not saying that the sequence of partial sums $x_k =\sum_{n=1}^k\frac 1 {2^n} $ will eventually have a term with value $1$, we are saying that it approaches $1$, and we define that value as the 'infinite sum' of the series.

Comment: Thank you, This is what my original thoughts were but multiple people were saying it was wrong for some reason and refusing to elaborate, which led to the horrible phrasing of the question. Thank you for clearing up the issue.

Comment: you are right, my bad. I'll correct the mistake right now @kimchilover

Comment: Thank you @kimchilover

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your question is the phrase

> an infinitely small amount off

since there is no such thing as an infinitely small number. That's not how to deal with the impossibility of

> actually add(ing) together all of the terms .

Mathematicians have found a way around that problem by requiring instead that the error in the partial sums be
*as small as you like*
provided you add up *enough terms*. How many that must be depends on how small you want the error to be, but each individual calculation is just a finite sum with an answer some actual distance away from what you want the sum to be.

Comment: Thank you, so if i understand correctly as the error approaches 0 (adding more terms), the number that the sum approaches will be considered the infinite sum?

Comment: Yes. The limit of the partial sums is _by definition_ the "infinite sum".